# How to migrate 'new.code' function to python 3

Tags: python

Could you please help migrating this old python2 code from [remotely](https://pypi.org/project/remotely/) to python3:

```
import new, dis

cell_changer_code = new.code(
    1, 1, 2, 0,
    ''.join([
        chr(dis.opmap['LOAD_FAST']), '\x00\x00',
        chr(dis.opmap['DUP_TOP']),
        chr(dis.opmap['STORE_DEREF']), '\x00\x00',
        chr(dis.opmap['RETURN_VALUE'])
    ]), 
    (), (), ('newval',), '<nowhere>', 'cell_changer', 1, '', ('c',), ()
)

def change_cell_value(cell, newval):
    return new.function(cell_changer_code, {}, None, (), (cell,))(newval)
```

The '*dis*' library seems to be still actual, while the '*new*' is replaced by '*types*' according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/new.html). But I have no idea how to implement it with '*types*'

Comment: Have a look at the python library [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/2to3.html?highlight=import%20new) it automatically converts python 2 code to python 3

Comment: I ran 2to3, modernize and futurize on it, but it hasn't been migrated.

Comment: The only other things I've found that could be of help are [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/code.html?highlight=code#code.compile_command) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile)